# Manipulating PSD and converting to TGA with Java

Tags: java, javax.imageio, psd, tga, twelvemonkeys

I have a few PSD that are basically templates with a few hidden layers. I want to manipulate these templates so that for every export only one of these hidden layers is visible. In the end these file should be exported as TGA.

I am looking for a way to do that programmatically with Java. I found TwelveMonkeys ImageIO (https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) but couldn't find a way to accomplish what I want (is there maybe a good documentation?). How can I do that? Is it even possible with that library? Are there other libraries that should be considered?

Comment: How about sharing one of your PSDs?

Comment: With TwelveMonkeys you can't hide/show layers in the PSD. However, you can read individual layers (optionally compose/merge them yourself), and export them in a different file format. This seems to be all you need. The library doesn't have TGA (Targa) export, but as the format is fairly simply you could add that yourself (perhaps contribute it to the project? :-) ) or suggest that as a new feature in the issue tracker.

Comment: PS: Why do you need to export as TGA?

Comment: @haraldK thank you for the hint. I'll look into that when I get to it again. I want to use the image files for a racing simulation which expects the TGA format. I will possibly look into the code and see if I can make a contribution to it.

Comment: How about sharing one of your PSDs?

Comment: @MarkSetchell don't think that'll help. Just imagine a PSD file with invisible layers on top of everything of which I'd like to make only one visible for each export.

Comment: Update: TwelveMonkeys ImageIO can now export TGA.

Comment: @haraldK oh, thanks for the notice. I'm gonna try it out.